# Setting a Woocommerce product category image programatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried:

```
wp_update_term(8, 'thumbnail_id', array(
'term_id' => 1517
));
```

where 8 is the id of the Woocommerce product category and 1517 is the id of the media image. After running this code however I cannot see a product category having the image set.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
update_term_meta(8, 'thumbnail_id', 1517);
```